# return xdocument from wcf service

Tags: wcf, linq-to-xml

How can i return xdocument from wcf service??? what i need to do to let wxf service's method return a object of xdocument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't.  XDocument does not implements IXmlSerializable.  XElement implement IXmlSerializable so you can transfer it through WCF.

You can also transfer a string instead of the XDocument and parse it locally.

Ex :

Server :

```
public string DoSomething()
{
    XDocument myXDocument = new XDocument();

    // Do stuff

    return myXDocument.ToString();
}
```

Client :

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(myWebService.DoSomething());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also return an XElement object.

```
    public XElement DoSomething()
    {
        XDocument myXDocument = new XDocument();

        //  Load the XDocument.

        return myXDocument.Root;
    }
```

Comment: 50% of programming is finding the right incantation. Thanks!